# Update cell value based on different file's cells

Tags: excel, python-2.7, cell, updates, openpyxl

I'm writing my first code (have to start with something :) ) and I'm really struggling with it as I couldn't find any similar example on the internet to give me at least a direction to take.
I will try to be as clearest as I can to explain it.

I have two .xlsx files with departments, all containing many districts.

```
FILE 1 - DATAS DEPENDING ON DISTRICT            FILE 2 - DISTRICT UNIQUE
                                                         VALUES
columnA+B  columnC       columnE                columnA        columnE
DATA       DEPARTMENT    DISTRICT               DEPARTMENT     DISTRICT 

"          LIMA          BARRANCA               LIMA           BARRANCA
"          LORETO        BARRANCA               LORETO         BARRANCA1
"          LORETO        BARRANCA               SAN MARTIN     BARRANQUITA
"          SAN MARTIN    BARRANQUITA            LORETO         BELEN
"          SAN MARTIN    BARRANQUITA            CAJAMARCA      BELLAVISTA
"          SAN MARTIN    BARRANQUITA            PIURA          BELLAVISTA1
"          LORETO        BELEN                  SAN MARTIN     BELLAVISTA2
"          SAN MARTIN    BELLAVISTA
```

As you can see, districts can have same names, but duplicates belongs to different department.
My expected result is to update FILE 1 as follows:

```
columnA+B  columnC       columnE                columnA        columnE
DATA       DEPARTMENT    DISTRICT               DEPARTMENT     DISTRICT 

"          LIMA          BARRANCA               LIMA           BARRANCA
"          LORETO        BARRANCA1              LORETO         BARRANCA1
"          LORETO        BARRANCA1              SAN MARTIN     BARRANQUITA
"          SAN MARTIN    BARRANQUITA            LORETO         BELEN
"          SAN MARTIN    BARRANQUITA            CAJAMARCA      BELLAVISTA
"          SAN MARTIN    BARRANQUITA            PIURA          BELLAVISTA1
"          LORETO        BELEN                  SAN MARTIN     BELLAVISTA2
"          SAN MARTIN    BELLAVISTA2
```

Any suggestions for a tool that can help me? I tried a code with simple for loops but I can't figure out how to make it in 4 columns in the same time.

```
wb1 = FILE1
ws1 = worksheet1
wb2 = FILE2
ws2 = worksheet2

x=1
for distr1 in ws1['E']:
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(1,ws2.max_row+1),  range(1,ws1.max_row+1)):
        distr2 = ws2.cell(row=i,column=5)
        dept2 = ws2.cell(row=i, column=1)
        dept1 = ws1.cell(row=j, column=3)
        if distr2.value == str(distr1.value) + str(x) and dept2.value == dept1.value:
            distr1.value = distr2.value
        x +=1
```

Probably not the best code in this world but as I said, my first one :)

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. Are you simply attempting to merge the two files?

Comment: No it's a bit more complicated. The district's names have duplicates sometimes: so they have incremental suffixes to be unique values in FILE2. It's not the case in the FILE1 but I can't just add a random suffix to them: they have to be the same than in FILE2, regarding to the department they are attached to. Hope it's a bit clearer .

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, particularly which values should be kept. I would be tempted to create a lookup table from the second file which maps districts to departments and suffix. The following is pseudo code but should give you enough to work with.

```
from collections import defaultdict
districts = defaultdict(dict)
import re
dist_regex = re.compile(r"(?P<district>[A-Za-z])+(?P<suffix>[0-9]?)"

for row in ws2.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=5):
    dept = row[0]
    m = dist_regex.match(row[-1]).groupdict()
    dist = m['district']
    suffix = m['suffix']
    districts[dist][dept] = suffix
```

This should give you something like

```
{'BARRANCA': {'LIMA':None}, {'LORETO':'1',…}
```

You can then loop through the rows of the first file check whether the combination of district and department has a suffix and add it as necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, I  will keep in the direction you showed me and try to find the solution!